# recover linux partition after failed windows xp install

Tags: linux, multi-boot, partition-recovery

I have a pc with two hard drives, one runs Ubuntu 10.10 and the other has NTFS with a broken XP.   The XP failed after I upgrade Ubuntu to 10.10.   I installed virtualbox in Ubuntu so for a while I was happy with the setting.

Recently I needed to revive the XP to a dual boot since I need to test a piece of hardware that cannot be done in a virtual machine setting.   So I inserted the XP install CD and rebooted the machine.   When I hit the return to install XP, I noticed that the XP install CD did not recognise hard drives correctly: reporting the linux hard drives in a much smaller sizes and as C drive of unknown type.   For the second drive, it reports a few unpartitioned space and an NTFS partition.  I tried to see if I can install XP in the unpartitioned space but failed.   For fearing erase my linux hard drive, I decided to abandon the effort.  However the damage is already there: Ubuntu 10.10 is gone.

I booted the machine with a Ubuntu 10.10 live CD, it could not recognise the linux hard drive any more.   Testdisk told me that the linux hard drive is now in a FAT file system.  I tried a few testdisk commands in vain to restore any linux partition and then I realised I had better stop messing with it further.

In this case, what is the best way, if any, to recover the partition and data in the linux hard drive?

Comment: Does GParted report that the partition is deleted? If it does, you're screwed - there's no way to recover data from a nuked partition. Unless you want to `grep` for all your important information, which would be rather tedious.

Comment: First, make an image backup, and experiment on that.